# Team GO Rocket Bosses haven’t appeared in 1 year. Am I locked out?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 3 special researches that require to complete a Team Go Rocket Boss but the bosses haven’t appeared in a year using iPhone. The special researches are “Misunderstood mischief”, “Silent Schemes”, “Aloha to Aloha”.  What can I do to reset or start having these bosses to appear again?
I’m level 44.

Comment: Can you join a raid using remote raid pass?

Comment: Yes I can.  I just can’t battle cliff or Giovanni

Comment: @Mastermuon So you're asking about rocket bosses, not raid bosses

Comment: Just to confirm, you did beat 6 minions and activated the "Radar" afterwards, right? As far as I know, if you have an active Radar you should always see a boss when interacting with the flying balloon that appears every 6 hours. (though it might not be the boss you want, e.g. it could be Sierra instead of Cliff, just check again later if that's the case)

Answer (score 2):

Cliff is a Team Rocket leader. In order to encounter a leader make sure you Rocket Radar is equipped. To be sure go in items, disable the radar (if enabled), and enable it. Then, in order to encounter a leader, either wait for the next balloon or click on radar to check the map, which will show which Pokestop has a leader on it.

Giovanni is a Team Rocket Boss. The only way to encounter him is enabling the black Rocket Radar. If you don't have one, you can't encounter him. If you have it, follow the same procedure as for the leader with regular rocket radar.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Pokemon Go re-released the bosses, and now you can find them in Team Rocket Balloons or sometimes captured Pokestops.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-released the leaders"? The team rocket leaders were never taken out. You can find them in the rock balloons and pokestops as long as you have the rocket radar